# How to create ImGui window and render to it at any time you want?

Tags: c++, imgui

I don't know much about ImGui, and it's also poorly documented.
I'd like to know if there is a way to create an ImGui window, and then render to it anytime you want. I only know this way of creating a window:

```
ImGui::Begin("Window");
ImGui::Button("Button");
ImGui::End();
```

Comment: just to touch on: `it's poorly documented`...
see: https://imgui-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
and more importantly check out the examples: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples
You'll find everything you need there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply use `ImGui::Begin` and `ImGui::End` with the appropriate window title again if you want to append to a window.

The following works:

```
ImGui::Begin("Window A");
ImGui::Text("This is window A");
ImGui::End();

ImGui::Begin("Window B");
ImGui::Text("This is window B");
ImGui::End();

ImGui::Begin("Window A");
ImGui::Button("Button on window A");
ImGui::End();

ImGui::Begin("Window B");
ImGui::Button("Button on window B");
ImGui::End();
```

It produces two windows that like this:

[image: windows]

Regarding poor documentation, you are right. The library authors [provide a list of resources](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#q-where-is-the-documentation) that can serve as documentation material.

Comment: I didn't know this, Thanks!

Comment: @Uytab Glad I helped!